# Using MongoDB for a Matchmaking Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, roblox

I'm trying to make an external web server for matchmaking on Roblox using Node.js. I'm wanting to use MongoDB for a backend database, but with lobbies being made and deleted so quick, would that work? I have 2GB of RAM and 1 CPU core on a DigitalOcean droplet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MongoDB for something such as match-making lobbies for Roblox seems very excessive, especially since Roblox provides `DataStoreService` for things such as this. I'm sure using DataStoreService should be able to fulfill your needs, even with the lobbies being created and deleted quickly. Many of the frequently played match-making games use it, and they don't have too many problems.

I'd even argue that using an external database such as MongoDB would be worse for your game. If lobbies are being created and removed as fast as you suggest, you'd surely hit the low request limit, which would create a lot of inconsistencies throughout your game servers, making it difficult to play.